# Is there a way to have powershell skip a depth of a directory like I can with folders?

Tags: powershell

Apologies if this has been asked but I haven't found an answer.

I'm writing a script that deletes all files not used within 2 weeks, and deletes all empty folders.

I simply use '\*' at the end of my file path to skip the topmost level of folders, as I want to retain these.

I also want to retain files at this level, but for some reason my code ignores the '\*'. Does anyone know why?

**Path**

`$dPath = 'C:\Users\my.name\Desktop\PowTest2 - Copy\*\'`

**Folder Function**

```
function Get-jkEmptyFolderList 
{ 
    [cmdletBinding()]
        param (
        [string] $fPath
    )

    $condition = Get-ChildItem $fPath|                      
                Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | 
                Where-Object{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | 
                select FullName; 
                
                write-verbose 'Test point 1'
                write-verbose   ($result | Out-String)

                 return $condition
}
```

**File function**

```
function Get-jkEmptyFileList{
[cmdletBinding()]
        param (
        [string] $fPath
    )

$result = Get-ChildItem  $fPath -Recurse -force |                                                   
    Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime –lt $RefDate } |
    Where-object {!($_.psiscontainer) } |                                               
    Select-object FullName, LastAccessTime, Length                          
    
    write-verbose 'Test point 1'
    write-verbose ($result | Out-String)
    
    return $result;
}
```

The script works exactly as I want except for this small issue; any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "my code ignores the `'\*'`"? What happens when you run these functions (that shouldn't be happening)?

Comment: Hi, of course. 

Putting "\\* " at the end of the file path allows me to skip to the next depth of the directory, ignoring the first layer of folders.

The folder function works as expected. If i put in the file path \\yellow\green\\*, it will go to the folder green, skip all of the folders in green and begin listing the empty folders in green's subfolders.

The same is true for the file function, except it doesn't skip, it scans all of the files at the depth of \\* aswell.